# aws cli fails s3 copy with parameter validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On Windows Server 2008 R2 (64), copying a file to s3 bucket:

> aws s3 cp somefile.bak s3://bucket/

```
*Parameter validation failed: Invalid type for parameter UploadId, value: None, type: <type 'NoneType'>, valid  types: <type 'basestring'>*
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI 64-bit version on Windows Server seems to be the issue.  I had run the 64-bit install since the machine is 64-bit. I uninstalled that version and installed 32-bit and it's working great.